# Alert Dialog doesn't adapt to Dark Mode and non-dark mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-theme, material-components-android

Why doesn't my Alert Dialog adapt to my phone's Dark Mode? When Dark Mode is activated in my phone, the two buttons' text is barely visible, while the title and message colors are inverted. why aren't buttons color inverted as well? The icon also doesn't appear well in non-dark mode. how to fix all of this?

[image]
[image]

```
  val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.title))
  builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.message))

  builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.positive)) { dialog, which ->
        
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, getString(R.string.pos_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  }

  builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.negative)) { dialog, which ->

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, getString(R.string.negative_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  }

  builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
  builder.show()
```

my stiles.xml:

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="generalnotitle" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Which app theme are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti please see edit.

Comment: For me, the problem was with using `Light` theme instead of `DayNight`. when I changed the whole app's theme to `DayNight` version, it fixed it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you are using a Material Components Theme just use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` instead of `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL") { dialog, which ->
                // Respond to neutral button press
            }
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
                // Respond to positive button press
            }
            .show()
```

The default text color of the buttons are based on this selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image]

Just check the **`colorPrimary`** defined in your app theme for the dark mode.

If you want to change the text color of the buttons you can override the `colorPrimary` using:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.Theme_MyApp_Dialog_Alert)
```

with:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dialog.Alert" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">

    <!-- Text Color for Buttons -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: ok i still accepted your answer, i put my own color. but why don't the text color change on its own like the title and message?

Comment: @Panjeet I've updated the answer. The text color of the button is based on the `colorPrimary`. You have to check in your app theme if you defined `colorPrimary` in your `values-night` folder. The text message and title are based on `colorOnSurface`. If you haven't defined it in the app theme there is a default value.